Can we add custom object as a related list to quick text standard object page layout
I have created one custom object "Quick text comments" and I created a lookup field to the "Quick Text" standard object. In my custom object, I am planning to collect comments about every quick text that I create.  I have added the custom object in the "Quick Text" page layout also but unfortunately, the custom object is not showing up on my Quick Text details page. I couldn't find any article that this is a known issue or it's not possible in Quick Text. Any insights on this will help me a lot.
